# WebKitBrowser and Iframe - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, iframe, webkit, browser, frames

At first , You need to know that this is my first question and i'm from Poland so very sory for any mistake.

I'm making program in VB.net.
I have site , not my , and there are Iframe. In the iframe is a text input. I need to change value of this input .

I make this in WebBrowser , but i need to make it in WebKitBrowser .
In WebBrowser this looks like:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames("NameOfFrame").Document.GetElementById("Text_Input").SetAttribute("value", "something")
```

In WebKitBrowser this don't work.

I'm trying this:

```
    For Each oneelement As WebKit.DOM.Node In WebKitBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NameOfFrame").ChildNodes

        MsgBox(oneelement.NodeValue.ToString)
    Next
```

One problem ..
I'm getting the msg:

"You need iframe support!"